# Logstash optional fields in logfile

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm trying to parse a logfile using grok

Each line of the logfile has fields separated by commas:

```
13,home,ABC,Get,,Private, Public,1.2.3 ecc...
```

I'm using match like this:
`match => [ "message", "%{NUMBER:requestId},%{WORD:ServerHost},%{WORD:Service},`...

My question is: Can I allow optional field?
At times some of the fileds might be empty `,,`

Is there a pattern that matches a string like this `2.3.5` ?
( a kind of version number )

Comment: Apart from the grok filter the [csv filter](http://logstash.net/docs/latest/filters/csv) is made for parsing this type of data.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

At it's base, grok is based on regular expressions, so you can surround a pattern with `()?` to make it optional -- for example `(%{NUMBER:requestId})?,`

If there isn't a grok pattern that suits your needs, you can always create a named extraction like this: `(?<version>[\d\.]+)` which would extract into version, a string that has any number of digits and dots in it.

Comment: Excellent answer! I have same problem and your answer saved me hours for searching!

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly for me too. @Alcanzar I've seen you answer other questions - what good references do you recommend? I find there's a context gap between the grok docs and the underlying reg-exp references!

Comment: Just an observation, that the optional modifier does not seem to apply for the GREEDYDATA pattern. For example:  `(%{GREEDYDATA:x})? %{IP:ipaddr} (%{GREEDYDATA:y})?`

Comment: @ifelsemonkey Facing the same issue. Will post an answer if get any solution or workaround.

Comment: We used the (%{DATA:x})?