# grok have patterns to skip value

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

My grok patterns have problem skip value. Please help me to fix my patterns.

My value:

> 2013-02-28 09:57:56,SERVICEID|0863591797|topup|C00000001||10.0|20170110|N|aaa|bbb|ccc|aaaaabbb|ccccc|kkkkk|hhhhh

My grok pattern:

```
^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\,%{WORD:SERVICE}\|%{WORD:MSISDN}\|%{WORD:RULEID}\|%{WORD:CAMPCODE}\|(?:.*|%{WORD:CURRENT})\|(?<EVENTVALUE>(?:%{BASE10NUM}))\|%{WORD:EVNETDTTM}\|%{WORD:NEXTWAVE}\|%{GREEDYDATA:NAMEVALUEPAIR}
```

EVENTVALUE should be 10.0 but can't this value after parsing '20170110'
and EVNETDTTM is 'N'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'n not sure what you're trying to achieve but following grok expression should match your message:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\,%{WORD:SERVICE}\|%{WORD:MSISDN}\|%{WORD:RULEID}\|%{WORD:CAMPCODE}\|\|%{NUMBER:CURRENT}\|%{WORD:EVNETDTTM}\|%{WORD:NEXTWAVE}\|%{GREEDYDATA:NAMEVALUEPAIR}
```

Results on https://grokconstructor.appspot.com:
[image: results]

---

Edit: If the two backslashes mean that there might be an optional value in between there you could use the following pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\,%{WORD:SERVICE}\|%{WORD:MSISDN}\|%{WORD:RULEID}\|%{WORD:CAMPCODE}\|(%{WORD:CURRENT})?\|%{NUMBER:EVNETDTTM}\|%{WORD:NEXTWAVE}\|%{GREEDYDATA:NAMEVALUEPAIR}
```

`(%{WORD:CURRENT})?` means that CURRENT will be optional, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083719/logstash-optional-fields-in-logfile) for more details.

New results:
[image: new results]

Comment: This field "CURRENT" have value null i need to keep null in this filed.my Grok need to read every filed if some filed have null value. i need to keep it not to skip

Comment: I saw it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the filter plugin csv. If you grok out the timestamp and the comma (like in your grok) you could specify the "|" as separator for the csv plugin.