# Paring log text through grok filter in logstash on the given log structure

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

```
2019-04-01 10:57:35|[a1vx4d9r - ecaf-myself - N2PENL-ECFA0141.india.airtel.itm - servlet:/reserveNumbers/getAvailableNumbers/v1?httpMethodRestrict=POST ][[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '36' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO|com.airtel.common.aop.LogExecutionTime|EXECUTION TIME LOGGING METHODNAME: postResponseFromESB EXECUTION TIME: 472 ms
```

Above is the log format.

Please help in writing a grok filter in logstash that separates the fields as shown below:

```
timestamp: 2019-04-01 10:57:35
user_id:a1vx4d9r
project name: ecaf-myself
host_name: N2PENL
api_name:ECFA0141.india.airtel.itm - servlet:/reserveNumbers/getAvailableNumbers/v1?httpMethodRestrict=POST 
thread_id: [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '36' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
log_level: INFO
Method_name:postResponseFromESB 
Method_time:472
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing grok filters are easy with all the required patterns already defined [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns). You could use this app to try out your grok filter, and see if it is matching your log pattern: http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

For the above example, the below grok filter will work. You can check and fine tune it to fit your needs using the above two resources:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}.*\[%{WORD:user_id}* - %{NOTSPACE:project_name}* - %{WORD:host_name}*-%{DATA:api_name} \]%{GREEDYDATA:thread}\] %{WORD:log_level}.*METHODNAME: %{WORD:Method_name}.*EXECUTION TIME: %{INT:Method_time}
```

Comment: Sir, in case suppose user_id is not present and log be like-  2019-04-01 10:57:35|[a1vx4d9r -  -  - servlet:/reserveNumbers/getAvailableNumbers/v1?httpMethodRestrict=POST ][[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '36' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO|com.airtel.common.aop.LogExecutionTime|EXECUTION TIME LOGGING METHODNAME: postResponseFromESB EXECUTION TIME: 472 ms . How to avoid grokparseFailure in case any field is not present and thus, we are not able to extract the same.

Comment: if a field is absent for some entries, it means that the field is optional. Look at this question for handling such fields: [Logstash-optional-fields-in-logfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083719/logstash-optional-fields-in-logfile)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990067/parsing-through-grok-filter   - Please help in this answer.